# Where does the touchpad cursor go?

Tags: touchpad, hp, 18.10

I have been bragging on and encouraging all my friends to install Ubuntu on their desktops and laptops for some time now. I finally got one friend to allow me to rid his HP 15 TouchSmart of the plagued Windows X and installed Ubuntu 18.10 from an installation flash drive I used on my own pc and HP laptops.

Now it runs smoother, faster and wonderfully more efficient for him, since he’s even less computer savvy than I am. With one problem.

The screen touch works for selecting icons and opening things with a double tap on it.  But his touchpad and buttons for left clicking and right clicking are totally non-responsive.

I searched and installed the Gnome Tweaks 3 program, which fixed someone else’s right click problem, hoping it would fix his as well to no extent.  The touch pad is still completely unresponsive and neither button works.

He is an older gentleman, so I would like to return his laptop in full working condition.

Other than the Gnome Tweaks software for Ubuntu 18.04 I could find nothing related to this problem.

I did follow the links above, but with his laptop when I open the mouse&touchpad option there is no touchpad section, only a selection of primary button choice. His laptop has a touchpad ( and touch screen capabilities as well ) and both were working with a dual install of Windows X and Ubuntu 16.04

Is there a link or answer I overlooked or am missing in my searches?

Thank you.

Comment: touchpads don't often work out of the box especially on newer hardware. for my ASUS TUF504GM it didn't, I updated kernel then it did, then later I checked with stock kernel + new updates. The new updates alone had also resolved it. So first run updates and reboot, that could do it, if not run : `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa -y && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ukuu -y` and then run ukuu from start and get a kernel one or two versions above yours, maybe don't go 5.+, it's a bit beta still. you're pretty lucky, you have wifi working out of the box, I didn't. stay 18.10

Comment: I will try update first. But there seems to be a misunderstanding. His laptop came with Windows 8 installed, he “upgraded” to Windows X (against my advice btw) and allowed me to install Ubuntu 16.04 back then.  The touchpad and screen touch have both been working until I removed Windows X completely and did a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.10

Comment: yeah that's possible. a kernel update could fix it. drivers are a real issue moving from 16.04 to 18.04/10. btw I personally have nothing against win10, the whole "Microsoft" and telemetry bits aside (knowing those come with win8 as well). win8 was better than 7 in a power user sense but win10 is the most poweruser/ linux-ey of them all.

Comment: The update didn’t resolve it. Even after a reboot, so I’m installing the ukuu and updating from 4.18.0.16.17 to 4.19

Comment: maybe a tad further like 4.20.17

Comment: It jumps from 4.20.17 to 5.0, so I’ll try what just installed then try 4.20.17. ... if I need to I’ll try 5.0 or higher, hopefully not.

Comment: oh ok. do all the 4.20 versions jump to 5?

Comment: No need. The one I installed fixed the problem. Touchpad cursor, click buttons and Touchscreen all working now.   Thank you so very much.  He will be overjoyed.

Comment: i'll provide an answer, mark it please this will help others with the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue comes from too new trackpads that are just barely being added to the linux kernel as we speak,

fear not! you may use your trackpad on ubuntu yet!

simply open a trusty terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), run :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa -y &&
sudo apt-get update &&
sudo apt-get install ukuu -y
```

then, from your start menu, open up "ukuu"

use it to update your kernel to 4.19 or higher.

your trakpad should work after a reboot, cheers!