# Touchpad not working in Ubuntu 16.04.3 on Lenovo Ideapad 330

Tags: touchpad, lenovo

I have Windows 10 on my Lenovo laptop ideapad 330. I have installed Ubuntu 16.04.3 and my touchpad is not working on Ubuntu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where does the touchpad cursor go?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1129122/where-does-the-touchpad-cursor-go)

Comment: it you try the solution I just referenced what happens for you?

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `uname -r; dmesg | grep -i elan`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem on a lubuntu 18.04 just doing a upgrade:

```
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```